# Finding the integral values

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

The integral values of $a$ for which the equation $cos^2x-(a^2+a+5)|cosx|+(a^3+3a^2+2a+6)$ has real solutions. This question is from a math quiz so the answer cannot be that long..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Expression is equivalent to
$$
(|\cos x| - (a^2 + 2))(|\cos x| - (a + 3))=0
$$

Only solution comes from when $|\cos x| = a + 3$. So
$$
-1 \leq a+3 \leq 1
$$

Comment: Of course..I was unable to factor this out can you explain how were you able to see the factors so quickly

Comment: Well, if you see $|\cos x|$ like the unknown parameter here, your problem looks like a quadratic equation. Then, to study the solution you either calculate the discriminant or factor it. Since you said this should be an easy problem, I factored it :)